# Python. Asking user to input file name

Tags: python

I'm currently taking a python course and this bit of code is not working on VSCode or my command prompt. I really don't know what the problem is, could anyone help me?

```
fname = input()
fhand = open(fname)
count = 0
for line in fhand:
    if line.startswith('Subject:'):
        count = count + 1
print('There were', count, 'subject lines in', fname)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'fhand' is not defined
>>> print('There were', count, 'subject lines in', fname)
There were 0 subject lines in fhand = open(fname)
```

Currently working with Python 3.9.

[image]

Comment: Does your text file belong to the same directory of code file?

Comment: i didn't see any problem in your code. did you post the same code you are getting the error?

Comment: You are copying and pasting the code into a Python interpreter. When it gets to the `input()` line, it takes the next row of pasted text as input, instead of interpreting it as code. Try just clicking the green triangle at the top to run the whole script file instead. Or only paste code up to `input()`, then type a filename, then paste the rest.

Comment: I'll be damned. Thank you very much everyone for your responses. Matthias you were correct.

Answer (score 3):

Are you running the code in the Python interpreter?

It seems the first line is executed and the second line goes as the input to the first line. Therefore, `fname` is being set to `fhand = open(fname)`.

This causes no variable defined as `fhand`, and hence the error name `fhand` is not defined.

The count is set to 0, therefore the print statement gives the output

> There were 0 subject lines in fhand = open(fname)

**[Solution]**
Try saving the code to a `.py` file and then run it using:

```
python3 <fileName.py>
```